# JQuery Click event loads before change event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am using a simplified example to describe the issue I am facing.

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<input ng-model="something" style="margin-top:8px;"/>
```

And, I have two HTML buttons:

```
<button id='submit'>Save</button>
    
<button id='btnGetAnalyzerInput'>Generate Analyzer File </button>
```

I used jQuery's `change` event on my input (to track whether any changes have been made to the input - by maintaining a simple JS variable).

When the user clicks "Generate Analyzer file button", what I want to is this:

1. Look up the JS variable to find out whether any changes have been made.
2. If yes, then prompt the user to save changes (`window.dialog`)

However, I find that when the focus is still on the input element, and when the button is clicked, the `click` event runs before the `OnChange` event. In all other cases, it is the `OnChange` event which gets fired before the click event (and so my code works as expected).

Is there any way to ensure that for such a scenario, the click event runs after the `onChange` event?

I am using Google Chrome to test my application.

***Note :***

1. Both events work as expected - the `OnChange` event gets fired when the textbox loses focus.
2. I can't use the keypress event since I want to track changes.

Comment: Can you provide the JS part of your code....??

Answer (score 1):

You could have the click event call the same function as the OnChange event. Something like this:

```
function OnChange(){
  //Do stuff for on change;
}
function ClickEvent(){
  OnChange(); 
  //continue with generate stuff
}
```

You you may need to set up and pass in arguments to the OnChange function, depending on how you are accessing the data you need. If you need more guidance, post more of your code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.
What I want is to determine whether, the OnChange event has ever been fired. If it has, then I want to do something different in the click event.
The issue is that for the scenario described above, the click event gets fired before the change event - which breaks my logic.

Appreciate if you could help me with this.